# fading scrollMenu with labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

i've created a paged UIScrollView which contains labels on every page. How can i lower the margin between the labels like in the picture and then still being able to scroll?

At the moment my navigationBar look like following. Where u can swipe to next page to the right and get the next label.

[image]

What i want is something like this with a small margin and still being able to swipe.

[image]

## viewDidLoad code

```
    //Category ScrollView
    categoryScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height-38, self.view.frame.width, 38))
    categoryScrollView?.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, 38)
    categoryScrollView?.delegate = self
    categoryScrollView?.pagingEnabled = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(categoryScrollView!)
    
    categoryArray = NSArray(objects: "Book", "Elektronik")
    
    var textWidth = 0
    
    for val in categoryArray!
    {
        var textLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
        textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        textLabel.text = val as NSString
        textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(textWidth), 0, categoryScrollView!.frame.width, categoryScrollView!.frame.height)
            
            
        categoryScrollView?.addSubview(textLabel)
        
        textWidth = textWidth + Int(textLabel.frame.size.width)
        
        if textWidth > Int(self.view.frame.width) {
            categoryScrollView?.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(textWidth), categoryScrollView!.frame.height);
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default width of the "page" when `pagingEnabled` is switched on is the width of the scroll view. You could reduce the width and let the contained views be visible beyond the edges of the view by setting `clipsToBounds` to `false`.

If this does not work for you there also the option to adjust the paging width by intercepting the end of the drag via the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewWillEndDragging(...)` where you can adjust the `targetContentOffset` to fit your needs (see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19853632/427083)).