# Move to next cell, not to next page, UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a vertical collectionView, and cell which height is `collectionView.height*0.9`
in this case when I am setting `collectionView.isPagingEnabled` to true, after scrolling it moves to next page not to next cell.
I have tried almost all solutions mentioned here, with `customLayouts`, other libs, but all of them dont have enough smoothness while scrolling, or sometimes moves 2 cells while scrolling.

Is there any method to change collectionView page size?

Comment: Are the content insets correctly set?

Comment: I guess so, right now I am using https://github.com/Arnoymous/InfiniteLayout, but its not enough smooth
maybe I need to add gesture, remove all collectionView gestures and while swipeing move to next one.

Comment: Why don't you turn the pagination off and use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/19853632/1264313