# UIScrollView costum pagination size

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, pagination

first take a look on this picture from localScope app :

[image: localScope]

i have 2 (simple?) questions :

1. how can i paginate my icons like this?
2. how can i detect witch icon is " selected "

thank you.

Comment: What is a "Uiscrolview"? Please put a little more effort into your questions.

Comment: i miss an 'L' its not the and of world !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one clean & memory efficient approach is to have a `UINavigationController` & `UIToolBar` like so -

[image]

When the user taps on any button in the `UIToolBar` invoke that particular `viewController` by popping and pushing them.

I hope its clear that the look and feel can be achieved close to what you are showing in the image, I am talking about the functionality.

Comment: thank you, in fact you are right, its the 'normal' way to do it in ios but i want to try something new :)

Comment: you can try something new even by using the normal way ;) what i mean is the underlying implementation can be this time tested way (using uitoolbar+naviagation...) but the UI & look-feel you can do innovations. Skys the limit there.

Comment: i miss an "L" and i got -1 ok !!

Comment: Srikar, your approach is the best way to do what i need because i have just 3 icons, so  i'll use a customized tabbar.thank's

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to the first question:** You have to make your scroll view as big as the page size, enable its `pagingEnabled` property, then somehow make it to display elements and respond to touches outside of its bounds. See this code and these links:

```
@interface SmallPagedScrollView: UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIEdgeInsets responseInsets;
    NSMutableArray *items;
}

@implementation SmallPagedScrollView

@synthesize responseInsets;

- (id)init
{
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)]))
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.clipsToBounds = NO;

    CGFloat hInset = 3 * self.width / 2;
    self.responseInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, hInset, 0.0f, hInset);
    self.delegate = self;

    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
[items release];
[super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
CGPoint parentLocation = [self convertPoint:point toView:self.superview];
CGRect responseRect = self.frame;
responseRect.origin.x -= self.responseInsets.left;
responseRect.origin.y -= self.responseInsets.top;
responseRect.size.width += self.responseInsets.left + self.responseInsets.right;
responseRect.size.height += self.responseInsets.top + self.responseInsets.bottom;

return CGRectContainsPoint(responseRect, parentLocation);
}
```

See also [Paging UIScrollView in increments smaller than frame size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677085/paging-uiscrollview-in-increments-smaller-than-content-size) (Split's answer)

**Answer to the second question:** you can calculate the selected page using this formula:

```
int selectedIndex = (scrollView.contentOffset + scrollView.size.width / 2) / scrollView.size.width;
```

Comment: thank you i'll try this tomorrow at work and will tell you if i do it and how.

Comment: to be honest, i was not able to make this work and i found "MHPagingScrollView" to do what i need, but i still want to know how this work, so i'm looking to her source code. but in the end i think that Srikar solution is the best approach for me because i have just 3 icons to scroll.ill use a customized tabbar.