# Custom scroll in Cocos2D Layer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccscrolllayer

Please see image. How can I create custom scroll layer like this in cocos2D game? I used CCScrollLayer but that scrolls one page at a time. I want to scroll only one sprite on scroll.

Is it possible to do same with CCScrollLayer ? If not then is how can I do this?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved a similar thing by overlaying a UIScrollView over top of my cocos2d scene and then following this answer. I like using UIScrollView's over CCScrollLayer because you get the nice bounce and it is not hard to add UIKit objects in cocos2d 2.0.

[Paging UIScrollView in increments smaller than frame size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677085/paging-uiscrollview-in-increments-smaller-than-content-size)

Comment: Do you actually override scrollViewDidScroll and move Cocos2D layer to new position?

Comment: Doesn't the mix of UIScrollView and Cocos2D kill performance?