# Extending a vertical UIScrollView with pagingEnabled under the navigation and status bars

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I'm trying to extend a vertical UIScrollView with pagingEnabled underneath the navigation and status bars.

For other, non-paging scroll views, increasing the frame upwards and adjusting contentInset works fine. However, doing this with a paging scroll view affects the amount paged each swipe – effectively breaking paging as the pages don't line up to the height paged.

Trying to use [this sort of solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677085/paging-uiscrollview-in-increments-smaller-than-frame-size), i.e. maintaining the frame the same size and setting clipsToBounds = NO, kindof works. However, it only displays the above cell if it's actually visible within the frame – the 66 pixels underneath the status and navigation bars don't count.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

On your view controller you will need to set

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

This should effectively stop adding the extra spacing above the view.