# UIScrollView with Paging

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I am struggling with a problem related to uiscrollview.I need to load 3 images simultaneously into a scrollview like the attached image.If there is only one image the then that image should be shown centrally .If there are two images then first image should be shown centrally and half of the next image should be shown right to it.If there are three images then half of the first then second image centrally and finally half of third image .If the user scrolls it then the third image should come center,second should go first(show only half) and also the fourth image if any should load next.I am attaching my requirement here ,Looking for a solution thanks in advance...
[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220354/uiscrollview-horizontal-paging-like-mobile-safari-tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find a better solution using core animation than using a scrollview.  For example each of these images can be a CALayer or even a UIImageView that you can place and move around in a parent view or layer.