# how to drag 2 scrollview simultaneously?

Tags: iphone

It's an interesting effect in some magazine. When man swipes, left scrollview and right one will move simultaneously, but with different scoll speed. So sometimes the image in both left and right scrollviews will match together.

Is there any public api to change the scroll speed? I can't find it.

So I try to use scrollViewDidScroll: to control one scrollview from another, but there's alway timedelay between 2 scrollviews. When i move one scrollview, the other will move after about half second. So they aren't simultaneously any more.

Do any one now how to implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the scroll speed for this. What you can do is make your own animation.
You could just create your own scrollView format and the scroll part, and you'd have to do your own math with whatever timer you are using to make the scrolling look smooth and scroll-like. If you don't believe me, check these out.
1. [Change the speed of setContentOffset:animated:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404745/change-the-speed-of-setcontentoffsetanimated)
2. [UIScrollView scrolling speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815993/uiscrollview-scrolling-speed)
3. [Change the 'Gravity' on a UIScrollView with Paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974631/change-the-gravity-on-a-uiscrollview-with-paging)
4. [iPhone UIScrollView Speed Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719753/iphone-uiscrollview-speed-check)

the first 3 links are questions similar to yours, the 4th is someone asking how to check the speed of the scroll.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So i should use my own animation to create the 2 scrollview effect?

Comment: No problem, I hope I saved you some time from looking for ways to modify the speed.