# UIScrollView with horizontal paging using UIView as Subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uiscrollview, subviews

I have seen answers for this following question. I am new to swift programming and I am trying to implement a similar feature. I just wondered if you had any guidance on how to achieve this in swift 3 Xcode 8. I have been searching around for a suitable solution but I've had no luck.

I am trying use UIViews as a subview of UIscrollviews. I would also like to have each view fill the screen when pressed and shows another UIView. I have seen a similar feature on the GOLF app by 'Tyler the Creator'

The feature I am trying achieve is pictured below.

Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

This is a representation of the feature I am trying to create.

[image]

Comment: Much much easier if you use `UIPageViewController` than a scroll view. Just about everything is done for you. Easy to find lots of tutorials and samples - just search for `uipageviewcontroller tutorial swift 3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618780/uiscrollview-with-pagination-showing-part-of-the-previous-following-pages Tutorial: https://medium.com/@tingyishih/paginated-scroll-view-with-partial-previous-next-page-visible-655159fcdd50

Comment: @user8263946 Hi, Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    let scrollView : UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, 
    width: 250, height: 300))
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .orange
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    let numberOfPages :Int = 5
    let padding : CGFloat = 15
    let viewWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width - 2 * padding
    let viewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height - 2 * padding

    var x : CGFloat = 0

    for i in 0...numberOfPages{
        let view: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x + padding, y: padding, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        scrollView .addSubview(view)

        x = view.frame.origin.x + viewWidth + padding
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:x+padding, height:scrollView.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: I tried the solution and it's scrolling fine, but it does not show part of the next card.

Comment: nice, but I'd recommend using constraints. At least it would work fine with auto rotation

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var colors:[UIColor] = [.red, .blue, .green, .yellow]
var frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .orange
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    let numberOfPages :Int = 3
    let padding : CGFloat = 15
    let viewWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width - 2 * padding
    let viewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height - 2 * padding

    var x : CGFloat = 0

    for i in 0...numberOfPages{
        let view: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x + padding, y: padding, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight))
        view.backgroundColor = colors[i]
        scrollView .addSubview(view)
        x = view.frame.origin.x + viewWidth + padding
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:x+padding, height:scrollView.frame.size.height)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: It's Working,Try it

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIPageViewController. That class is exactly meant to do what you are looking for with ease.
See [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller)

You can embed your UIPageViewController in a UIContainerView to fit it anywhere.

Comment: That's a different use-case. `UIPageViewController` requires you to have multiple `UIViewController`s. `UIScrollView` works with a single, large `UIView`.