# Swipe between multiple CollectionViews in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I hope someone can help me.

I would like to swipe left and right between several CollectionViews and add another CollectionView in Runtime with a button on the last page.

How could I build up the structure?

My purpose: The user can create his own smart grid to create different shortcuts in each CollectionView item. I want to add more "pages" now.

Thank you!

[>> I have attached a picture of how it should work <<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csW3q.jpg)

**EDIT:** I found something helpful for my case:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIMRn_LdvOg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIScrollView with horizontal paging using UIView as Subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087479/uiscrollview-with-horizontal-paging-using-uiview-as-subviews)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of ways you can do that. One way is to use [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) where each UICollectionView is hosted by a UIViewController (or UICollectionViewController)