# Setting UIScrollView position after each scroll

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

i have a scroll View which contains 10 images on a row.
the fiarst 5 items will display on the screen at first time
the remaining 5 images will display only after the scroll.

However ,I need to display only one image per each scroll.

Details

---

```
i have 10 images in my scroll view on a row.
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th images will dispaly at the firt time.
when first scroll is done , i need to dispaly the 2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th images
after next scroll,i need to dispaly the 3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th images
after next scroll,i need to dispaly the 4th,5th,6th,7th,8th images etc.
```

is there any way to do it?
can any one provide me a good way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the [paging](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/pagingEnabled) property in `UIScrollView` class.

Also you can stop scrolling in `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` when image 6 will appear. After second scroll stop when image 7 will appear etc.

Comment: if we set paging property is True, it will didplay the next 5 images after scroll. not from the 2nd onwards.Thanks for your valuable reply

Answer (score 1):

Setting UISCrollView Position:

[myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height) animated:NO];

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use paging functionality for your case? If I right you can try making your scrollview less than the size of the screen (width-wise), but uncheck the "Clip Subviews" checkbox in IB. See more in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220354/uiscrollview-horizontal-paging-like-mobile-safari-tabs).