# UIScrollView Hittest function in monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I am having a problem with my UIScrollView,I want to implement a safari like scroll view with paging. I've used this link 
[UIScrollView horizontal paging like Mobile Safari tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220354/uiscrollview-horizontal-paging-like-mobile-safari-tabs)
As my refrence, all what I am missing right now is how to implement the hittest method.
I am using monotouch and I can't find any proper documentation on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Override the UIView HitTest method:

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIView.HitTest(System.Drawing.PointF%2cMonoTouch.UIKit.UIEvent)

Answer (score 1):

From the [MT Rosetta Stone](http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html):

```
Selector: hitTest:withEvent:    
Method: UIView HitTest (PointF point, UIEvent uievent);
```