# UIScrollView Paging with Preloading

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, paging

I implemented a paging UIScrollView. Therefore I have got 5 subviews on my scrollview. To have a nice effect I set up a little offset to every subview so that on the first page, you can see a little bit of the second page at the right side of the ipad. The same effect on the other pages, so everytime you are on a page you have got a little preview on the left/right side of your screen. The scrolling between pages works perfect, but the problem is, that at the first time, the preview isn't loaded. I got a textview on every subview, but it loads first after I scroll to the next page. So my preview doesn't work correct. How can I do something like a preloading, so that my other subview pages are loaded before I switch to them?

Thanks for your help, I hope I could explain it that its clear...
Andy

[image: preview page loading]

Code:

XIB:
I have got one UIScrollView, Size 750, 700. My Customview is 700,700.

```
resultScrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
resultScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
resultScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

[resultScrollView addSubview:[self createCustomSubView:0.0f :VIEW_OFFSET_BETWEEN :VIEW_WIDTH :VIEW_HEIGHT]];
[resultScrollView addSubview:[self createCustomSubView.frame.size.width :VIEW_OFFSET_BETWEEN :VIEW_WIDTH :VIEW_HEIGHT]];
[resultScrollView addSubview:[self createCustomSubView:2*resultScrollView.frame.size.width :VIEW_OFFSET_BETWEEN :VIEW_WIDTH :VIEW_HEIGHT]];
[resultScrollView addSubview:[self createCustomSubView:3*resultScrollView.frame.size.width :VIEW_OFFSET_BETWEEN :VIEW_WIDTH :VIEW_HEIGHT]];
[resultScrollView addSubview:[self createCustomSubView:4*resultScrollView.frame.size.width :VIEW_OFFSET_BETWEEN :VIEW_WIDTH :VIEW_HEIGHT]];

resultScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(5*resultScrollView.frame.size.width+5*VIEW_OFFSET_BETWEEN, resultScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

The method:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(contentOffset + betweenOffset, 0.0f, width, height);
NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomSubview" owner:self options:nil];
CustomSubview *customSubView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
CustomSubview.frame = frame;
CustomSubview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
CustomSubview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(VIEW_SCROLLABLE_CONTENT_WIDTH, VIEW_SCROLLABLE_CONTENT_HEIGHT);
```

Comment: are the subviews just UIViews?

Comment: the subviews extend from UIScrollview, because every page should be vertically scrollable too.

Comment: I did the same offset trick to show a bit of the other subviews before, can you edit your post to show some code of how you're adding the subviews please ?

Comment: I did it. But I found out now that the problem is only the textview on my customview. As example, a label is preloaded and I can see it as a preview. 

But I think this code is like a hack, perhaps you have a better solution to do that? Because with my code I cant really change something easy, as example if I want to have more place between each subview, that doesnt work. And now I can only touch on my subviews - not between, because there is no scrollview.

Comment: I think you have to rethink how you're doing placing and setting up the main scrollView, as for only being able to touch the subview:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/1220354/870155