# How to use Page enabled UIScrollView with contente size greater than scrollView width

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

Can some one please tell me how to do this. 
My scrollView width is 600 and I'm going to 3 UIViews which has width of 800. Please note that this is a iPad app. Unfortunately I cant change the width of scrollView or UIView. I want to scroll through the one UIView completely without changing the page. If user drag further scrollview should jump to the second view. I want to do this by enabling paging in the scroll view.So there will be 3pages not 4. Is this possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1220605/1405008 refer this

Comment: It is for UIView width less than the UIScrollView's width right? I need it to do other way arround. UIView's width is greater than the scrollview's width

Comment: once you enable the pagging the thing you want is difficult to achive, but you can to this by your own without paggin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updating my answer according to your updated question.**  
1- first we add a `scrollView` (outer scrollView) with any frame you like

2- inside this scrollView (the outer) there is 3 inner-scrollViews with frame.size.width = outerScrollView.frame.size.width.

3- every inner scrollView has a standard scrolling behaviour (not paging) and the contentSize.width of them is equal to the yourView.size.width (lets assume 800 as in your question)

4- add every view on different inner-scrollView and then add these scrollViews(with view as a subview) on the `outer-scrollView` with paging enabled. The contentSize of the outer scrollView is equal to = outerScrollView.frame.size.with * 3.

***Now you should have the inner-ScrollView scrollable to the size of your view, and when you reach the end of the contentSize  the outer scrollview will change to the next page.***

Comment: I did the way you asked. But seems it not working. now pagecount = (800*3)/600=4. I want only 3 pages so that one UIView can view without changing the page

Comment: @nath, updated my answer, let me know if you have any question

Comment: ahh.. thanks dude... I'll try this and let you know if there is anything.

Answer (score 0):

The `contentSize` must be greater than the `UIScrollView` width or it won't scroll.

Create a `UIView` with width 2400 that contains your 3 `UIView`s. Add that `UIView` container to the `UIScrollView` and set the `UIScrollView` contentSize to 2400 width.

Comment: This is not give what I have expected. I have edit the question bit take a look at now